# Conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'd like the date / time that is in the past to turn red.

The table has dates and time in different formats.

Can I use one rule to do everything?

If not is it possible to do so?

I've tried `=today()` to turn text red but it doesn't respond.

Update: OK it works for the cells that only have dates. Can I do this for the other cells that have a mix of date, text, time?

[trial](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kZK5uagH8OdF_txPrP3tLdeyafz2DLw6z9BVx2NGKco/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your shift key appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O6418jirH3WlbDGBZWEpKGLXjl2QfqC4BdSOwpqiccM/pubhtml). I've used the Custom Formula =AND(ISDATE(B2),B2>=NOW()) to conditionally format the range B2:F12. ISDATE() avoids formatting cells with contents like "This isn't relevant", which Google Sheets considers to be >= NOW() — Boolean operations in Google Sheets do no type checking.  *I deliberately haven't formatted the selected cells red, since that was in a lot of cells that weren't getting conditional formatting in your example.* Hope this is helpful!